# efficiently getting value of many radio buttons from page

Tags: php, html, sql, brute-force

My application is a math quiz and I must get the value of many radio buttons from this page to use to calculate score and whatnot.

As of right now I designate ten separate variables for each radio button, but this sounds like brute force coding to me. Does anyone have a more efficient way in doing this? Here's my current code below.

```
//these variables hold which radio button the user selected
$answerChoice1 = $_POST['test1']; //pulls value of radio button named test 1
$answerChoice2 = $_POST['test2'];
$answerChoice3 = $_POST['test3'];
$answerChoice4 = $_POST['test4'];
$answerChoice5 = $_POST['test5'];
$answerChoice6 = $_POST['test6'];
$answerChoice7 = $_POST['test7'];
$answerChoice8 = $_POST['test8'];
$answerChoice9 = $_POST['test9'];
$answerChoice10 = $_POST['test10'];

$questionID1 = $_POST['theId1']; //pulls the 'bid' of the question asked
$questionID2 = $_POST['theId2'];
$questionID3 = $_POST['theId3'];
$questionID4 = $_POST['theId4'];
$questionID5 = $_POST['theId5'];
$questionID6 = $_POST['theId6'];
$questionID7 = $_POST['theId7'];
$questionID8 = $_POST['theId8'];
$questionID9 = $_POST['theId9'];
$questionID10 = $_POST['theId10'];

$sqlAnswer1 = "SELECT * FROM `math` WHERE `bid` = \"" . $questionID1 . "\"  "; //sql statement for selecting the questions that were generated
$sqlAnswer2 = "SELECT * FROM `math` WHERE `bid` = \"" . $questionID2 . "\"  "; //on the page
$sqlAnswer3 = "SELECT * FROM `math` WHERE `bid` = \"" . $questionID3 . "\"  ";
$sqlAnswer4 = "SELECT * FROM `math` WHERE `bid` = \"" . $questionID4 . "\"  ";
$sqlAnswer5 = "SELECT * FROM `math` WHERE `bid` = \"" . $questionID5 . "\"  ";
$sqlAnswer6 = "SELECT * FROM `math` WHERE `bid` = \"" . $questionID6 . "\"  ";
$sqlAnswer7 = "SELECT * FROM `math` WHERE `bid` = \"" . $questionID7 . "\"  ";
$sqlAnswer8 = "SELECT * FROM `math` WHERE `bid` = \"" . $questionID8 . "\"  ";
$sqlAnswer9 = "SELECT * FROM `math` WHERE `bid` = \"" . $questionID9 . "\"  ";
$sqlAnswer10 = "SELECT * FROM `math` WHERE `bid` = \"" . $questionID10 . "\"  ";
```

See how clunky and ugly this code is? Also underneath these sql statements I have ten separate queries for each statement. Any ideas?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Also, this is prone to SQL injection. Please consider using [PDO and prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php).

Comment: Also try `<input type="radio" name="test[]"><input type="radio" name="test[]"><input type="radio" name="test[]">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without altering your mark-up, you can just make a loop to read and process the variables:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++)
{
  $answerChoice = $_POST["test$i"];
  $questionID = $_POST["theId$i"]; //pulls the 'bid' of the question asked

  $sqlAnswer = "SELECT * FROM `math` WHERE `bid` = \"" . $questionID . "\"  ";

  // Execute the other stuff within the loop as well, if it is per question.  
}
```

Note: I focused the snippet on optimizing your snippet as-is, because that's what you asked for, but it is still vulnerable to SQL injection. If someone forges a request that has some weird stuff in `$_POST["theId1"]`, that stuff will be part of your SQL query and can damage your database!

**About arrays**

***Normal***

```
// You can declare an array like this:
$answerChoices = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++)
{
  // Using the bracked notation, you can append an item to an array. 
  // You don't even have to specify an index. It will just start at 0.
  $answerChoices[] = $_POST["test$i"];

  // You *can* specify an index, though. Using -1 here to be in sync with the 0-based array above.
  $questionIDs[$i - 1] = $_POST["theId$i"]; //pulls the 'bid' of the question asked

  // You don't have to declare the array first. If you just add an item, PHP will 
  // create the array for you.
  $sqlAnswers[] = "SELECT * FROM `math` WHERE `bid` = \"" . $questionID . "\"  ";
}
```

You can loop through them like this:

```
foreach ($sqlAnswers as $i => $sqlAnswer) {

  echo $sqlAnswer; // This variable is generated in the foreach loop.

  echo $answerChoices[$i]; // For the other arrays you can use the index.
}
```

Of course, mixing the way you access the arrays, like above, might be confusing. Fortunately, you can still use a normal for loop using an integer index as well:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($answerChoices); $i++)
{
  echo $answerChoices[$i];
  echo $sqlAnswers[$i];
}
```

***Nested***

You can nest arrays too. And you can use strings as indexes. That way, you can structure your data a little better, so it's even easier to use it in the rest of your code.

```
$quizData = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++)
{
  $questionID => $_POST["theId$i"];

  // Not the best way, but for now a simple way to make your code a little 
  // safer, if question id is indeed an integer.
  $questionID = (int)$questionID;

  // Question, answer and SQL are stored in an array with string keys. 
  // That array is stored in $quizData, so it will be an array of arrays.
  $quizData[] = array(
    'answerChoice' => $_POST["test$i"],
    'questionID' => $questionID,
    'sqlAnswer' => "SELECT * FROM `math` WHERE `bid` = \"" . $questionID . "\"  ";
}
```

Now you have a nested array, where each item is an array with named indexes that contain the data.

Check this loop:

```
print_r($quizData); // Show the whole array in all its glory. ;)

foreach ($quizData as $questionData)
{
  print_r($questionData); // All data for a single question

  echo $questionData['questionID']; // Just one property of a question.
}
```

The next option would be objects, but I think I'm pushing the scope of the question. ;)

Comment: You can just throw $i inside the quotes? Wouldn't you have to concatenate the variable or is that not needed? Also, thanks for the response.

Comment: If you use double quotes, PHP will parse variables inside them. With single quotes this doesn't work. Concatenation would work too, use the `.` operator for that: `$_POST['theId' . $i]`.

Comment: Cool man, gonna try out this loop. My code should look a lot neater now, thanks.

Comment: Also, would you need to add in $i to the answerChoice and questionID variables? Cause in the loop your changing the value of the variable every iteration.

Comment: Exactly, but if you do all the processing inside the loop, you can just recycle the variables. If you don't want to do that, maybe *arrays* are the solution for you. I'll add a small snippet showing that in a minute, but for a more detailed description, you can have a look on PHP.net which contains all the documentation. It would be silly to copy all that here.

Comment: Yeah perhaps I can push all the items into an array within the loop and then compare indeces of them for calculating score?

Answer (score 1):

If you want more control over the variables, I would suggest you put your POST vars in an array.

`$answerChoice = array($_POST["test1"], $_POST["test2"], etc...)`
and then use a `for loop` to iterate over the array

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++){
$answerChoice[i]
//more code
}
```

This allows you to target certain answer choices with ease

Comment: Very clever. I tried this approach before, but it never actually pulled the data into the array. I'll give it another shot using your code. Thanks man